# There are several identical classes in the .module.scss file, but only one classname is returned

Tags: reactjs, next.js

how to separate with the same class name? :S
nextjs generated only one cloumn1 end cell1, cell2 class etc..
maybe it could be solved??: className={styles.left.column1}, className={styles.left.column1.cell1}, className={styles.right.column1}, className={styles.right.column1.cell1}

xy.module.scss

```
logo {
  conatiner {
    .left {
      .column1 {
        .cell1 {}
        .cell2 {}
        .cell3 {}
        etc..
      }
      .column2 {
        .cell1 {}
        .cell2 {}
        .cell3 {}
        etc..
      }
      etc..
    }
    .right {
      .column1 {
        .cell1 {}
        .cell2 {}
        .cell3 {}
        etc..
      }
      .column2 {
        .cell1 {}
        .cell2 {}
        .cell3 {}
        etc..
      }
      etc..
    }
  }
}
```

logo.tsx

```
import styles from './logo.module.scss'


<div className={styles.logo}>
  <div className={styles.container}>
    <div className={styles.left}>
      <div className={styles.column1}>
        <div className={styles.cell1}></div>
        <div className={styles.cell2}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.right}>
      <div className={styles.????????}>
        <div className={styles.???????}></div>
        <div className={styles.???????}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to apply different styles in different contexts to the same classname. For that, you need to rewrite `logo.module.scss` like this:

```
.left {
  & .column1 {
    & .cell1 {}
    & .cell2 {}
…
.right {
  & .column1 {
    & .cell1 {}
    & .cell2 {}
…
```

Nesting by itself does nothing. You need to use the `&` selector, which SCSS substitutes with the current selector, so the code above transpiles to:

```
.left {}
.left .column1 {}
.left .column1 .cell1 {}
.left .column1 .cell2 {}
…
.right {}
.right .column1 {}
.right .column1 .cell1 {}
.right .column1 .cell2 {}
…
```

So in `logo.tsx` you can simply write:

```
    <div className={styles.right}>
      <div className={styles.column1}>
        <div className={styles.cell1}></div>
        <div className={styles.cell2}></div>
```

And CSS descendant selector will do its job.

Hopefully this answer is what you need!